# Return counts for multi-level relational files in SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi

There are 3 tables, Business can have many Customers, who can have many Sites.

I need to have a report that for each business listing the total number of customers and sites.

```
    SELECT bus.BusinessID, 
       cb.CustomerBusinessID,
       s.SiteID FROM [dbo].[Business] bus
  left outer join CustomerBusiness cb on cb.BusinessID = bus.BusinessID
  left outer join Site s on cb.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
  Where bus.RecordStatus = 'A'
  and cb.RecordStatus = 'A'
  and s.Sitestatus= 'A'
  Order by Name
```

I have joined the files (see above) and I get lots of rows, but I don't understand now how I can get a listing of the businesses with their totals.

See below for some of my data.

So for business ID 33 (I didn't include the name yet, there should be 3 Customers and 10 Sites).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

This is the code that I got to work after making a slight change to the code Kate provided.

```
SELECT bus.Name as Business_Name,
       count(distinct tb.TruckerID) AS num_Truckers,  
       count(distinct cb.CustomerBusinessID) AS num_Customers,
       count(distinct s.SiteID) AS num_Sites  -- distinct probably unnecessary
FROM [dbo].[Business] bus
LEFT JOIN  TruckerBusiness tb
     ON tb.BusinessID = bus.BusinessID AND tb.RecordStatus = 'A'
LEFT JOIN  CustomerBusiness cb
     ON cb.BusinessID = bus.BusinessID AND cb.RecordStatus = 'A'
LEFT JOIN  Site s
     ON cb.CustomerID = s.CustomerID AND s.Sitestatus= 'A'
WHERE bus.RecordStatus = 'A'
Group BY bus.Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably `count(distinct)`:

```sql
SELECT bus.BusinessID, 
       count(distinct cb.CustomerBusinessID) AS num_businesses,
       count(distinct s.SiteID) AS num_sites  -- distinct probably unnecessary
FROM [dbo].[Business] bus LEFT JOIN
     CustomerBusiness cb
     ON cb.BusinessID = bus.BusinessID AND
        cb.RecordStatus = 'A' LEFT JOIN
     Site s
     ON cb.CustomerID = s.CustomerID AND
        s.Sitestatus = 'A'
WHERE bus.RecordStatus = 'A'
GROUP BY bus.BusinessID, Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

Note that I moved the filters on `cb` and `s` to the `on` clauses.  Otherwise, the `LEFT JOIN`s will be turned into `INNER JOIN`s so businesses with no customers or customers with no sites would not be included in the results.

Comment: This was very helpful. I did have to add a Group By clause and I also added another table that I wanted to get data on. I will edit my original question with the final code I came up with.